# Exported QGIS TIFF file is much bigger than inputed, even without edits

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, file-size

In using QGIS I have found that when I export a GeoTIFF it is 4x larger (in storage size) than the original TIFF file that I open in QGIS. What would cause this?

Comment: I checked the Resolution and it was LZW. I didn't see that type of compression in the Export screen. Any idea how to get that same type of compression? I have not been changing extent what-so-ever.

Comment: You could choose High compression in the Save Raster Layer As dialog box Create Options Profile drop down.  This will export using Deflate compression which may be smaller than lzw.  But if you want lzw double click on the word deflate and replace it with LZW.

Comment: To compress a dataset use gdal translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either in in the Processing Toolbox search for translate, or Right-Click export, then click the + and add the parameter COMPRESS with value LZW:

[image]

You can also select others compressions using the Profile menu, or manually like above. Click Help for available compressions